# Value Inside React Form Options not changing

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-forms

The value in the option dropdown does not change while selecting. It by default always sends the first option

```
<Form.Control required 
  as="select"                                       
  name="servicetype"                                                                    
  multiple={false}                                    
  value={this.state.servicetype}                                    
  onChange={this.serviceTypeChange}
  className={"bg-dark-text-white"}                                     
>


  {this.state.servicetype.map((servicetype, index) => (                                        
    <option key={index} value={servicetype}>{servicetype.type}</option>                                            
  ))}

</Form.Control>
```

my onchange method

```
serviceTypeChange = event => {
  this.setState({
    //[event.target.name]: [event.target.value]
    servicetype: this.state.servicetype,
  });
}
```

note-I am trying to send a json object on select

Comment: setState is asynchronous by nature, have you tried using it's callback signature?

Comment: @Mohit I am new to react, can you give some more info

Comment: In `onChange` you're setting same state and expecting change?

Comment: @Vaibhav  can you please tell how to update the state to new state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `serviceTypeChange`, you are updating the state with the same value instead of the new value received from the event (which you have commented out). Try this:

```
serviceTypeChange = event => {
  this.setState({
     ...this.state,
     servicetype: event.target.value,
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but getting this error

TypeError: this.state.servicetype.map is not a function

Comment: What is the value of `this.state.servicetype` when you log it? It is likely `null` or `undefined`? If it is meant to be an array of "servicetypes", it is a better idea to rename it to `this.state.serviceTypes`.

Comment: Also note that I've changed the field name from `serviceType` to `servicetype` to follow your original name convention. That might have caused the `this.state.servicetype` to become `null` or `undefined` in the first place.

Comment: Also to prevent this, try setting the initial state of `servicetype` to an empty array.
`state = { servicetype: [], ...otherState }`.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using same state variable to hold options & selected option. Use another variable for selected option.

```
state = {
  serviceTypeOptions: [], // for available options
  selectedServiceType: null, // for selected option
}
```

update in change handler

```
serviceTypeChange = event => {
  this.setState({
     selectedServiceType: event.target.value
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but selectedServiceType: "[object Object]" this is what is getting send in the json

Comment: try to log `event.target.value` in console, as it is object it must be automatically converted to JSON while submitting data

Comment: the new value itself is not getting selected, it always defaults to first value in dropdown, meanwhile getting this warning->The `value` prop supplied to <select> must be a scalar value if `multiple` is false.

Comment: Set `value = {this.state.selectedServiceType}` to `Form.Control` prop, then value will get reflected

Comment: still selecting the default value :)  thanks for the quick reply. don't know where am I making mistake

Comment: finally solved by adding <option key={index} value={JSON.stringify(servicetype1)}>{servicetype1.type}</option>

Comment: Don't think, this is the only way